# Output partial string of a certain index of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

C++ newbie here, I'm not sure if my title describes what I am trying to do perfectly, but basically I am trying to output one line of a string array for a certain index of that array.

For example: Say myArray[2] is the 3rd index of a string array, and it holds an entire paragraph, with each sentence separated by a newline character.

```
contents of myArray[2]: "This is just an example. 
                         This is the 2nd sentence in the paragraph.
                         This is the 3rd sentence in the paragraph."
```

I would like to output only the first sentence of the content held in the 3rd index of the string array.

```
Desired output: This is just an example.
```

So far I have only been able to output the entire paragraph instead of one sentence, using the basic:

```
cout << myArray[2] << endl;
```

But obviously this is not correct. I am assuming the best way to do this is to use the newline character in some way, but I am not sure how to go about that. I was thinking I could maybe copy the array into a new, temporary array which would hold in each index a sentence of the paragraph held in the original array index, but this seems like I am complicating the issue too much.

I have also tried to copy the string array into a vector, but that didn't seem to help my confusion.

Comment: Take a look at std::basic_string::find, std::basic_string::substring

Comment: Use `std::find()` to find the position of the 1st `'\n'` character, and use that with `std::string::substr()` as length.

Comment: Actually index 2 is the *third* element in any array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines

```
size_t end1stSentencePos = myArray[2].find('\n');
std::string firstSentence = end1stSentencePos != std::string::npos?
    myArray[2].substr(0,end1stSentencePos) :
    myArray[2];
cout << firstSentence << endl;
```

Here's the reference documentation of [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Answer (score 1):

Below is a general solution to your problem.

```
std::string findSentence(
    unsigned const stringIndex, 
    unsigned const sentenceIndex, 
    std::vector<std::string> const& stringArray, 
    char const delimiter = '\n')
{
    auto result = std::string{ "" };

    // If the string index is valid
    if(stringIndex < stringArray.size())
    {
        auto index    = unsigned{ 0 };
        auto posStart = std::string::size_type{ 0 };
        auto posEnd   = stringArray[stringIndex].find(delimiter);

        // Attempt to find the specified sentence
        while((posEnd != std::string::npos) && (index < sentenceIndex))
        {
            posStart = posEnd + 1;
            posEnd = stringArray[stringIndex].find(delimiter, posStart);
            index++;
        }

        // If the sentence was found, retrieve the substring.
        if(index == sentenceIndex)
        {
            result = stringArray[stringIndex].substr(posStart, (posEnd - posStart));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Where,

- `stringIndex` is the index of the string to search.
- `sentenceIndex` is the index of the sentence to retrieve.
- `stringArray` is your array (I used a `vector`) that contains all of the strings.
- `delimiter` is the character that specifies the end of a sentence (`\n` by default).

It is safe in that if an invalid string or sentence index is specified, it returns an empty string.

See a full example [here](http://ideone.com/PKi8RC).